# How can I order by multiple Items using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a collection and i am trying to take the "latest" item in the collection based on the following code:

```
 return MyCollection.OrderByDescending(a => a.StartDate).FirstOrDefault(a => a.StartDate.Date <= DateTime.UtcNow.Date));
```

This works great but I ran into an issue where I have an example where there are two entries in the MyCollection with the same start date. (so i assume it arbitrary takes one of them ??)

to deal with this situation, i want to add a check for this so if there are multiple items with the same startdate, it then goes to another field to decide which one to return but i don't want to have the expense of checking this second field unless the situation exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use `ThenBy()` or `ThenByDescending()`

```
return MyCollection.OrderByDescending(a => a.StartDate).ThenBy(a=>a.Fish).FirstOrDefault(a => a.StartDate <= DateTime.UtcNow.Date));
```

As you want the item with the latest date....

```
var max=MyCollection.Where(a => a.StartDate.Date <= DateTime.UtcNow.Date).Max(a=>a.StartDate);
result=MyCollection.Where(a=>a.StartDate == max).OrderBy(a=>a.SecondProp).First();
```

Comment: This doesn't take 'but i don't want to have the expense of checking this second field unless the situation exists.' in account

Comment: @Jan Jongboom: It's very possible that the Linq implementation actually uses a composite key which combines the OrderBy and ThenBy expressions, so the sorting is done only once. See Jon Skeet's implementation of OrderBy and ThenBy: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/07/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26d-fixing-the-key-selectors-and-yielding-early.aspx

Comment: Anyway I wouldn't bother about such "optimization" unless I profiled the application and found out that this particular line of code is my bottleneck.

Comment: Updated an answer to provide an answer with just the latest entry.  This woulder interate the collection twice but may end up being faster than the overhead of a full orderby

Comment: @Bob Vale - im confused.  are you suggestion the first or second answer

Comment: @ooo the first answer is the general way to  sort an entire collection by multiple keys.  The second answer is specifically for when you are only looking for a single answer. The second property is only inspected  on items with the latest date.

Answer (score 1):

you should find there is a `ThenBy` /`ThenByDescending` extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ThenBy()`, it's always executed. The only way to execute the 'ThenBy' only when the result from the `OrderBy` is equal, you'll have to write a custom [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could have your object support IComparable, put your logic in that then just order by the object itself `.OrderBy( a => a )`

(I think that works...otherwise you could pass in an object that implements IComparer to the OrderBy)